# Could we abstract over type classes?

Tags: haskell

I wonder if ithere is a deeper reason that we cannot abstract over type classes (or can we?).

For example, when we have

```
fzip :: (forall a.[a] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [c] -> [(b,c)]
fzip f xs ys = zip (f xs) (f ys)
```

then we can say

```
fzip (drop 42) [1..100] ['a'..'z']
fzip reverse   [1..100] ['a'..'z']
```

and so on. But we cannot

```
fzip (map succ) [1..100] ['a'..'z']
```

which we can fix with:

```
ezip :: (Enum b, Enum c) => (forall a.Enum a => [a] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [c] -> [(b,c)]
ezip f xs ys = zip (f xs) (f ys)
```

and likewise we can fix

```
fzip (map (5*)) [1..100] [1.5, 2.3, 4.7]
```

with

```
nzip :: (Num b, Num c) => (forall a.Num a => [a] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [c] -> [(b,c)]
nzip f xs ys = zip (f xs) (f ys)
```

But is it not embarassing that we cannot subsume `ezip` and `nzip` with something like:

```
gzip :: (g b, g c) => (forall a. g a => [a] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [c] -> [(b,c)]
```

though the code is absolutly identical, up to the name of the class?
Or can we somehow?

Interestingly, when instances were just records that contained functions, this would be easily possible.

Comment: GHC's `Constraint` system expects solvability to be *monomorphically decidable (in that all types with kind `Constraint` are predicated by one or more _known_ types - that is, a typeclass higherarchy can't be variadic in its typeclass header), I think that might be a lead

Answer (score 11):

You can *almost* do this with `ConstraintKinds`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Proxy

gzip :: (g b, g c) => Proxy g -> (forall a . g a => [a] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [c] -> [(b,c)]
gzip _ f xs ys = zip (f xs) (f ys)

test1 = gzip (Proxy :: Proxy Enum) (map succ) [1 .. 100] ['a' .. 'z']
test2 = gzip (Proxy :: Proxy Num) (map (5*)) [1 .. 100] [1.5, 2.3, 4.7]
```

The main difference is that you need the `Proxy` argument, because GHC is unable to infer the right instantiation for `g` without help.

Answer (score 8):

Add a [`Proxy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html) argument for the constraint:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}

import Data.Proxy

gzip :: (g b, g c) => Proxy g -> (forall a. g a => [a] -> [a]) -> [b] -> [c] -> [(b,c)]
gzip _ f bs cs = zip (f bs) (f cs)

> gzip (Proxy :: _ Enum) [0, 1] "ab"
[(1,'b'),(2,'c')]
```

GHC considers constraint parameters that only occur in constraints ambiguous, so we need to record them explicitly in a Proxy.

Comment: Interesting use of `PartialTypeSignatures`.

Comment: @kosmikus I'm tired of double Proxies :P

Comment: Yes. I'll certainly keep this in mind. Although I still don't really like that `PartialTypeSignatures` are somewhat conflating type-level holes with type-level code inference. I wish they'd be syntactically different like in Agda.

Comment: I hope that explicit type application in GHC 8.0 would let us get rid of `Proxy` and `KProxy` altogether (I wonder though what'll happen to the current "ambiguous types" error).

Comment: Yes, there'll hopefully be lots of new possibilities :)