# How to use an arbitrary makeFields lens argument with different types in the same function?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I am using `makeFields` from *lens* to generate fields overloaded for various structures. I would like to use these fields at one with multiple structures while having to state which field I want to use only once. It would look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Control.Lens

data A = A
    { _aX :: String
    , _aY :: String
    }
makeFields ''A

data B = B
     { _bX :: String -> Char
     , _bY :: String -> Bool
     }
makeFields ''B

-- x can get _aX from an A and _bX from a B

a :: A
a = undefined

b :: B
b = undefined


q :: (Getter A String) AND (Getter B (String -> a)) -> a
q lens = (b^.lens) (a^.lens)
```

Which type should I give `q`? I tried letting GHC infer the types, but that failed.

Comment: `(b^.lens) a^.lens` = `((b^.lens) a) ^. lens` but you probably want `(b^.lens) (a^.lens)`. However, the type `(Getter X Y, ...)` is not even valid (it is impredicative) so you have to use `ReifiedGetter` or writer `Getter A .. -> Getter B .. -> ..`.

Comment: @2426021684 Why do you need the two `Getter`s to be the _same_ lens?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson It does not have to be but passing the same lens to a function twice seems odd

Comment: Benjamin Hodgson's question is a more fundamental one. `aX` and `bX` have nothing to do with each other, and so you probably shouldn't expect to specify them both with a single parameter.

Comment: In my application a bunch of objects have the same properties and giving the same argument to a function 2 or 3 times seems repetitive

Comment: The point is that these properties are not the same. You consider them the same and would like to handle then homogeneously, but as far as the code in your question goes there is no connection between them. That means before writing the function you want you would need to find a way to abstract away the differences between the properties.

Comment: @2426021684 Before trying to run your code (which I only managed to do now) I hadn't actually noticed you are using `makeFields` rather than `makeLenses`. My mistake, though if your question had a bit more in the way of explanation of what you were actually doing the odds of it not getting misinterpreted would be better.

Comment: @2426021684 I have edited your question into something more immediately apprehensible. I strongly suspect that, had you presented it in such a way from the beginning, you would by now have more answers, or better answers, than you currently do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decide what is to be done, we need to know what the types of your (`makeField`-generated) fields are:

```
GHCi> :t x
x :: (HasX s a, Functor f) => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

So the abstraction covering all your `x`-bearing types (the abstraction I was whining about before noticing you were using `makeFields`) is a multi-parameter type class `HasX`, and similarly for the other fields. That gives us enough to use `x` with different types in a single implementation:

```
-- Additional extension required: FlexibleContexts
-- Note that GHC is able to infer this type.
qx :: (HasX t (a -> b), HasX s a) => t -> s -> b
qx t s = (t ^. x) (s ^. x)
```

```
GHCi> import Data.Maybe
GHCi> let testA = A "foo" "bar"
GHCi> let testB = B (fromMaybe 'ø' . listToMaybe) null
GHCi> qx testB testA
'f'
```

That, however, is not quite what you asked for. You wanted something like:

```
q xOrY b a = (b^.xOrY) (a^.xOrY)
```

Achieving that, however, requires abstracting over the *classes* `HasX`, `HasY`, etc. Doing so is, in fact, somewhat feasible thanks to the `ConstraintKinds` extension, as demonstrated in [*Could we abstract over type classes?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34029594/2751851) Here it goes:

```
-- Additional extensions required: ConstraintKinds, ScopedTypeVariables
-- Additional import required: Data.Proxy
-- GHC cannot infer this type.
q :: forall h s t a b. (h t (a -> b), h s a) => Proxy a -> Proxy h
  -> (forall u c. h u c => Getting c u c) -> t -> s -> b
q _ _ l t s =
    (t ^. (l :: Getting (a -> b) t (a -> b))) (s ^. (l :: Getting a s a))
```

```
GHCi> q (Proxy :: Proxy String) (Proxy :: Proxy HasX) x testB testA
'f'
```

The first proxy, which determines the intermediate type, is necessary unless you give up this bit of generality and replace `a` by `String`. Additionally, you have to specify the field twice, both by passing the getter as an argument and through the second proxy. I am not at all convinced that this second solution is worth the trouble -- the extra boilerplate of having to define `qx`, `qy`, etc. looks quite a bit less painful than all the circuitousness involved here. Still, if any of you who are reading this would like to suggest an improvement, I'm all ears.